# Reduce git checkout time?

Tags: azure-devops

So when I setup a service connection to bitbucket repo, the checkout out time in the build pipeline takes about 20 mins and then the build passes is there a way to increase the speed for git clone process ?

Answer (score 2):

Well look for shallow clone

Pass this only to get latest version of master (This will ignore the commit history). I assume that you only need latest branch code. The `--depth 1`  is the latest commit of the master branch.

```
git clone --depth 1 <YOUR_GIT_REPO_URL>
```

Comment: Hi Dashrath, thanks for responding, that did significantly droped the checkout time, however,  It takes a lot of time while publishing the code, like it took about 18 mins to publish it to the drop folder in the build agent, is there a workaround for that ?

Comment: @sameerkhan you want to drop the above cloned repository right?

Comment: if you want drop the git folder then try this ```git gc --aggressive --prune``` which normally remove the  garbage collection in your repository and prune old objects.

Comment: The reason that it takes too long to publish the artifacts may because there  is a large number of small files in artifact folder. The workaround is to use the `archive files task` to zip the artifacts files to a single .zip file. See [this thread](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/1480) for more information.